# Octals in regex: shouldn't this produce a warning?

Tags: perl

This program runs fine on perl 5.18.1:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010; # <--THIS

my $test = "Now\012is\012the\012time\012";
print $test;
$test =~ s/\o{12}//g;
print $test;
```

According to `perlrebackslash` ("Octal Escapes" section), the `\o{12}` syntax was introduced in 5.14. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use 5.010` just means you nead *at least* 5.10 to run the script. It doesn't turn off the new features introduced in 5.12, 5.14 etc. See [use](http://p3rl.org/use).

Answer (score 0):

There was no backwards compatibility to introducing `\o{12}`, so you don't need to activate that feature. It is available as long as you have a sufficiently high version of Perl.

The program's installer can insure you have a sufficiently high version of Perl, or you can add `use 5.014;`, but neither are necessary.